# Writing an SQL query to bring back results using a filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an SQL query to use within a filter on a webpage. The webpage is for an online recipe cookbook.

If you are logged into the system and go to your recipes only your user can see these recipes.

So for example lets say I created 3 recipes and one has broccoli in. I want to be able to choose broccoli in the ingredients filter and for it see what recipes I have saved with broccoli and display it. So I beleive the query needs to take 2 values which is the ingredient id and the users id, it needs to check which recipe has that ingredient in it and then if the user created that recipe, it then needs to return the recipe ID so we can display those recipes.

At the moment this is my query. However it brings back everything that user has made.

```
SELECT quantities.recipe_id
FROM quantities, recipes
WHERE quantities.ingredient_id = '24' AND recipes.user_id = '6'
```

Do I need to do a join somewhere?

Table structure for Recipes: 
[image: Recipe Table Structure]

Table Structure for Quantities
[image: Quantities Table Structure]

Comment: Show us the table structure for `quantities` and `recipes`.

Comment: Please show us your table structure to help with the exact query you want

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Sorry for not showing that. I have now edited the post show the table structure.

Comment: Join on recipe.id maybe?  WHERE ... AND quantities.recipe_id = recipes.recipe_id

Comment: @androidnation Sorry for not showing that. I have now edited the post showing the table structure.

Comment: If you are working with html and php form, please add some of them into your code so we can do a whole script and query

Comment: I think you're trying to run before you can walk. Familiarise yourself with some of the basic concepts of relational data and structured queries - joins in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a join. The better query would be:

```
SELECT quantities.recipe_id
FROM quantities
INNER JOIN recipes ON quantities.recipe_id = recipes.recipe_id
WHERE quantities.ingredient_id = 24 AND recipes.user_id = 6
```

Without the join, you're generating a product of every recipe row with every ingredient row, which is not what's intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT quantities.recipe_id
FROM quantities, recipes USING(recipe_id)
WHERE quantities.ingredient_id = '24' AND recipes.user_id = '6'
```

An alternative (shorter code) way to join when the field is named the same in both tables.